# Did Jesus leave hints as to the hour of His 2nd coming to earth (matt 24:30)?

Tags: second-coming, olivet-discourse

I suggest that Tribulation believers knew the Day of His return to earth with His angels. Matt 24:30

The first 1260 days of Daniel's 70th week. The Temple and 2 witnesses: "Rise and measure the temple of God, the altar, and those who worship there." Rev 11:1 "And I will give power to my two witnesses, and they will prophesy one thousand two hundred and sixty days, clothed in sackcloth." Rev 11:3

Followed by the mid-week abomination of desolation: "standing in the holy place...then let those who are in Judea flee (5343 escape) to the mountains." Matt 24:15, 16

Then the "great tribulation" Matt 24:21 for 1260 days: "it shall be for a time, times and half a time" Daniel 12:7b (3 1/2 years or 1260 days).

"...he was given authority to continue for forty-two months."... "It was granted to him to make war with the saints and to over come them. And authority was given him over very tribe, tongue, and nation." Rev 13:5, 7

"Then the woman fled into the wilderness, where she has a place prepared by God, that they should feed her there one thousand two hundred and sixty days" Rev 12:6 "... into the wilderness to her place where she is nourished for a time and times and half a time from the presence of the serpent." Rev 6:14

Therefore, I suggest Tribulation believers will see Him on day 1260.

As to the hour:

Hint 1 "I tell you in the night (nux, 3571) there will be two in one bed (kline, 2825) the one will be taken (paralambano, 3880) and the other left (aphiemi , 863). Luke 17:34

Hint 2 - "And if he should come in the second watch or come in the third watch ..." Luke 12:38 Note - second watch is from 9:00PM to midnight, third watch midnight to 3:00 AM.

Hint 3 - "And at Midnight ... the bridegroom is coming ..." Matt 25:6

Comment: Matt 25:13 - Therefore keep watch, because you do not know the day or the hour.  I accept this teaching of Jesus.  Anything that contradicts it is opposed to Jesus.

Comment: Matt 24:36 is an even stronger "no".

Comment: @Hank-See new answer by Ray Grant that does an expository approach to this Question.

Answer (score 1):

The 1260 days and the 490 days are separate, non-overlapping time periods that come from separate prophecies in Daniel.

**The 490 Days**

> <sup>24</sup>**Seventy weeks** are determined upon thy people and upon thy
> holy city, to finish the transgression, and to make an end of sins,
> and to make reconciliation for iniquity, and to bring in everlasting
> righteousness, and to seal up the vision and prophecy, and to anoint
> the most Holy. <sup>25</sup>Know therefore and understand, that from
> the going forth of the commandment to restore and to build Jerusalem
> unto the Messiah the Prince shall be seven weeks, and threescore and
> two weeks: the street shall be built again, and the wall, even in
> troublous times. (Daniel 9:24-25, KJV)

**The 1260 Days**

> And I heard the man clothed in linen, which was upon the waters of the
> river, when he held up his right hand and his left hand unto heaven,
> and sware by him that liveth for ever that it shall be for **a time,
> times, and an half;** and when he shall have accomplished to scatter the
> power of the holy people, all these things shall be finished.  (Daniel
> 12:7, KJV)

**The 1290 Days**

> And from the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and
> the abomination that maketh desolate set up, there shall be **a thousand
> two hundred and ninety days.** (Daniel 12:11, KJV)

**The 1335 Days**

> Blessed is he that waiteth, and cometh to **the thousand three hundred
> and five and thirty days.** (Daniel 12:12, KJV)

The 490 days (70 weeks) are the first of the 2300 days of Daniel 8:14, whereas the 1335 days of Daniel 12 are the last of the 2300 days.  The 1290 comes at the start of that 1335, and the 1260 begin 30 days later.  All of these "days," of course, represent years.

The 490/2300 began in 457 BC.  The first 7 weeks of this, i.e. 49 years, was the period of time during which the Second Temple was being built.  As the Jews told Jesus, it took 46 years to build it, and it was forced to a stop for legal hassles for several years.

The 69th "week" of the 70 brings us to AD 27, the year in which Jesus was baptized and began his ministry.  This starts the final "week," the one which is split in half.  In the middle of that week, Jesus is crucified.  The end of that week is AD 34--the time when Stephen is stoned and the Gospel truly begins to spread among the Gentiles.  This was the end of the Jews' grace period (forgiveness), according to Jesus' reiteration of the 490 prophecy.

> Jesus saith unto him, I say not unto thee, Until seven times: but,
> Until **seventy times seven.** (Matthew 18:22, KJV)

"Seventy times seven" is 490.

**All of these are fulfilled.**

These prophecies have already been fulfilled, the longest one reaching to AD 1844.  At the end of this longest time, another prophecy comes, found in Revelation, which ends any further declaration of times.

> <sup>5</sup>And the angel which I saw stand upon the sea and upon the
> earth lifted up his hand to heaven, <sup>6</sup>And sware by him that
> liveth for ever and ever, who created heaven, and the things that
> therein are, and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the
> sea, and the things which are therein, that **there should be time no
> longer:**" (Revelation 10:5-6, KJV)

This "time no longer" means that no more prophetic times will be given or applied.  (It obviously does not mean that time *itself* should cease to exist, as some have interpreted--that would be entirely unreasonable.)

The "time no longer" means that for the end-time events, we will not have a prophetic timeline to guide us.  No one will know when probation closes, when the seven last plagues will fall, or when Jesus will return.  We are told to "expect" these events as that of the coming of a thief in the night: a thief does not announce his arrival ahead of time.  Even Jesus himself claims not to know when these times will be.

> But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which
> are in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father. (Mark 13:32, KJV)

If Jesus does not know these times, we would be more than presumptuous to think *we* could know them.

### Conclusion

Jesus made it clear that we will *not* know the time of his coming, even apparently excluding himself from this knowledge.  While we are not in ignorance that the day is approaching, we do not know "the hour."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe Jesus gave us "signs" as to His second coming. His disciples were pointing out the temple buildings to Him. (Matthew 24:1). At vs2 Jesus says the following. "Do you not see all these things? Truly I say to you, not one stone here shall be left upon another, which will not be torn down."

His disciples at vs3 ask Him a very specific question? "Tell us, when will these things be, and what will be the sign of Your coming, AND THE END OF THE AGE/WORLD?"

Jesus then goes on to explain some of the things that will happen before His second coming. Nation against nation, many false prophets, you will be hated by nations on account of My name. You will be led astray, lawlessness is increased,(this is happening right now in a big way before our eyes in the USA). At vs8 Jesus says, "But all these things are merely the beginning of birth pangs." Vs13, some or even many believers will not persevere until the end of the Tribulation and hence will not survive those seven years.

Matthew 24:14, "And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in the whole world for a witness to all the nations, and the end shall come." Now comes the sign! Matthew 24:15, "Therefore when you see the Abomination of Desolation which was spoken of through Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place, (let the reader understand),

What are we to do, flee. From verses 16-28 we are given more bad news of what will happen. At verse 29, "But immediately AFTER the tribulation of those days the tribulation of those days The Sun will be darkened, and the Moon will not give its light, and the stars will fall from the sky, and the powers of the heavens will be shaken, and the Son of Man will appear in the sky etc.

At verse 31, "He/Jesus Christ will gather His elect from one end of the sky to the other. I believe the biggest sign or hint if you will is when we see the Abomination of Desolation standing in the Holy place.

Comment: Mr. Bond - I agree that the Abomination Of Desolation standing in the Holy place is a big sign but I respectfully disagree that it occurs at v31. As I stated the temple has to built with the 2 witnesses in the first 1/2 of Daniel's 70th week or 1260 days. Rev 11:1, 3

Answer (score 0):

> > *Did Jesus leave hints as to the hour of His Second Coming?*

**No Hints, No Way!** Several hermeneutical, exegetical considerations provide an answer in the Negative!  First of all, when the disciples asked their questions, they used the Greek word for the End of the World, *sunteleias* ,which was the same word Jesus had used in Matthew 13:39, referring to the End-time Harvest (End of World). But when Jesus answered their questions, He used the Greek word, *telos*, which just means the end of an Age---in this case, the End of the Jewish Age (Mosaic, sacrificial age).

**Old Testament Imagery** Realize that Jesus used Old Testament imagery that designated the Fall of a Nation (in this case the Fall of Israel). This use of atmospheric language throws off many Western, English-speaking readers. (vs. 29-30) All the statements in these verses have been explained in Marcellus Kik, *Matthew Tewnty-four*, and Raymond Grant, *Times, They Are A'Changing*.

**Book-ends** Thirdly, notice that the the whole first half of this Olivet Discourse is couched between two *book-ends* which same the same thing:  *I tell you the truth, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened.* (23:36, 24:34) Anything mentioned in between happened in the first century (30-70 A.D.), according to Jesus.

**But Concerning** And finally, notice that when the End of the World (Second Coming) is dealt with, Jesus introduced it with the emphatic Greek words, *peri de* ("but concerning that Day or Hour...). A definite break in subject matter!  And then Jesus continued with the giving of illustrations showing there would be NO SIGNS at the Second Coming.  His **repetition** should be an emphasis to us of the fact of NO SIGNS.

END OF JUDAISM 24:1-34----->transition 24:35-36----->END OF WORLD 24:36-25:46